# MS Access 2013 Select in Insert Into shows input popup instead of doing query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert, ms-access-2013

I can't seem to figure out why this SQL code is showing an input popup instead of inserting the data from the second table. Am I doing something wrong?

```
INSERT INTO tblThroughputCalculations ([Estimated Total]) 
SELECT tblLocations.[Total Starting] FROM tblLocations 
WHERE ID=tblThroughputCalculations.[Incident Name]
```

The input popup asks for the value of `tblThroughputCalculations.[Incident Name]`

Comment: Try the SELECT FROM WHERE part on its own, and you'll see that it can't work. -- Actually your query makes little sense as it is, are you sure you want an INSERT query, not an UPDATE query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though there isn't a field named **Incident Name** in your **tblThroughputCalculations** table.

Check to see if it the field in the table doesn't have a space or is named differently.

Now that I think about it, I think your query is wrong - you have tblThroughputCalculations in your where clause but it's not JOINed to the tbllocations.